# GWT 2.7.0 taking more time for junit test case when comparing with GWT 2.4

Tags: junit, gwt

I have upgrade my GWT project from 2.4 to 2.7. 
While running the junit on my project using ant, I have found that it is taking too much time complete the unit test case.
In my project one of the component contains 3 test cases. In 2.4 it takes 68.408 seconds to run the junit test case, where as in 2.7 it takes 515.49 second.
In the junit log I have found that the 1st test case itself taking 513.65 seconds where as in 2.4 it is taking 66.561 second.

Also I have tried same with the StockWatcher sample program and found the followings:
**In 2.4**
Testcase: testGreetingService took 41.079 sec
Testcase: testFieldVerifier took 0.073 sec

**In 2.7** 
Testcase: testGreetingService took 89.113 sec
Testcase: testFieldVerifier took 0.075 sec

*NOTE: Did not modified anything build.xml file.*

So want to why there is so much time difference between 2.4 to 2.8 for junit build?